# Лишние символы в ответе сервера

Tags: php, сокет, клиент-сервер, apache2

Я уже задавал этот вопрос в английской ветке, но ответов не было. Надеюсь, это не есть дубликат...

С помощью сокета я подключаюсь к серверу `$stc = stream_socket_client("$url:80",$err,$ert);`, задаю запрос GET ($req содержит детали, там все ОК), считываю заголовки ответа, вывожу их на экран

```
fwrite($stc,$req);
$s = "";
$tmp = fgets($stc);
while($tmp!="\r\n"){
    $s.=$tmp.'<br>';
    $tmp = fgets($stc);
}
echo $s.'<br>';
```

Потом считываю тело ответа (таким же макаром, по-классике). С какого-то момента я заметил, что в теле ответа появляется стока-число (НЕХ) - четыре цифробуквы типа 34f2. Она обновляется с каждым новым запросом.

Мне не сложно от нее избавиться, распознать или учесть, но причина ее появления так и не разведана. Есть ли к-то идеи?

PS

при использовании cURL такой проблемы нет. Только сокет (наверно, следствие сложной обраотки в кодах cURL)

Comment: дак не на стороне сервера разведывать то надо?

Comment: @teran, сервер запрашивает сервер. Я на РНР пишу скрипт обращения к другому серверу и получаю его ответ по GET. И вот в этом ответе к-то недоразумения. Кстати, в cURL такого не наблюдалось - щас добавлю ремарку в вопрос...

Comment: гуглить по chunked

Comment: @Ипатьев похоже, оно! Напишите ответ - отмечу как нужный!

Comment: Лучше сами напишите по итогам, я деталей не помню, а у вас по горячим следам получится полезнее

Answer (score 2):

Если в заголовках ответа сервера не указывается длина данных

```
  Content-Length: 1234
```

то некоторые серверы разбивают ответ на блоки-чанки ([chunks](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)), указывая их длину в отдельной строке НЕХ-числом. Признаком длины чанка есть пустая строка

```
12А3
<!DOCTYPE html>
 ....
```