# шестнадцатеричные числа. Поиск в строке

Tags: php, jquery, xhtml, hex

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, а есть ли какие-нибудь варианты в длинной строке (несколько мегабайт) найти шестнадцатеричные числа? (что бы потом их вырезать)

Числа не определенные, варьрируются в диапазоне 30000-60000.

Вырезать в целом пофиг чем - можно php-шкой, можно каким-нибудь javascript-ом.

Пример из того, из чего надо вырезать, что бы было чуть яснее:

```
<City Code="1" Name="Moscow">
<Place Code="34" Name="Someplace" />
</City>
```

И шестнадцатеричное число может быть абсолютно в любом куске - хоть между = и ", хоть в середине слова Place - т.е. абсолютно в любом месте.

Метод получения всего этого выглядит так:

```
$sock = fsockopen($host, $port);
                fputs($sock, $post);
                $content = '';
                echo "<pre>";
                while (!feof($sock)) {
                    $content .= trim(fgets($sock));
                }
                echo htmlspecialchars($content);
                echo "</pre>";
                fclose($sock);
```

Comment: А такая регулярка не вырежет ли мне еще что-нибудь? (в строке так же содержаться и десятеричные числа, которые надо оставить (и они могут варьироваться от 0 до 1М... =\))

Comment: Нет, все же такой паттерн - не подходит. Вырезает все.

Comment: Привел пример. из чего вырезать, что бы стало чуть яснее. Сами по себе шестнадцатеричные числа - в крупном диапазоне....

Comment: `абсолютно в любом куске`, вот, например, в слове`Code` я вижу 2 числа: `c` и `de`

Comment: В этом то и проблема. При чем может еще и такая дата упасть: Cobff8de

Comment: @DantheHat, нужны более жесткие условия для нахождения чисел. Иначе только китайцев нанимать :Р

Comment: Увы, но числа получаются очень рандомные, и зависят от запроса. Мне бы знать как вообще от них избавиться без всяких велосипедов. (Числа пишутся когда получаю ответ от стороннего сервера в виде длинной xml-ки. получаю при помощи fgets в цикле, и при этом никогда не знаю размер получаемое строки (ибо получаемые данные достаточно рандомно выдаются в зависимости от города\дат и еще пачки параметров.))

Comment: Тогда вам поможет только вычитка с помощью человека, либо устранение корневой причины. Откуда вообще эти цифры берутся? По вашему описанию создается впечатление, что где-то тупо баг, либо у вас, либо на отдающем сервере

Comment: Добавил как я это получаю. Ответ на вопрос от куда эти цифры берутся - был бы решением проблемы, вероятно)

Comment: Есть подозрение, что эти артефакты появляются на каждой итерации `fgets($sock)`  (но доказать не могу). Попробуйте, ради интереса, чем нибудь другим забирать. Curl-ом например

Comment: Подозрение абсолютно верное. Но увы, компания отдающая данные - не поддерживает другие методы. ну точнее так: У нас есть запрос вида: Хидеры RequestName=имя_запроса&Login=логин&Password=пароль&xml=xml_строка_запроса. Все мои попытки отправить это Curl-ом не увенчались успехом и тех.поддержка конторы которая отдает данные сказали что они не в курсе как парсить curl-ом (

Comment: Все, ответ найден.  Помогла в результате вот эта тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648810/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Решилось тем что в хиддере было изменено HTTP/1.1 на HTTP/1.0